# How can I type/insert non printable characters on iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, unicode

I want to type some non printable characters inside a textbox of an iPhone app, including the null character and the carriage new line characters `\r\n`.

I've tried to type these characters on a PC and output the string to a web page, then use an iPhone to access the same page and copy it. However, it appears that the clipboard on iPhone would change the content it copied. For example, having `"hello\r\nworld"` on a web page, the clipboard on iPhone would strip the `"\r"` character and it would become `"hello\nworld"`.

I also found this from a [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Entering_special_characters#Keyboard_code), saying that there is some template for typing unicode characters, but I really have no idea how to use that.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Copying string from web page would behave differently across Linux/Mac and Unix, thats limitation of CRLF and LF.

You could install third party keyboards like swiftkey, flesky etc and give them a trial.

Or use web friendly characters like `&nbsp; , <br/>` for the characters you need.

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25d6/index.htm

Comment: But HTML character reference only works on certain environments (e.g. browsers), so it's not what I'm looking for. I'll try those two keyboards you mentioned. Thank you.